# Getting distance between elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to calculate the distance on the canvas dynamically (something like shown in fig.). I need to drag the highlighted joints so that calculating span can be increased / decreased. 
Does there exists any plugin for this? If not, can you give me some suggestions to do it effectively. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Distances are calculated thanks to Pythagoras: `dist(x1,y1,x2,y2) = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)`

Comment: @Kolink Distances are calculated thanks to math; Pythagoras just wrote the formula. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use Google closure, and it has a distance function:
http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_math_Coordinate.html

Not sure if that is an option for you, I personally recommend it if you have a complex drawing app.

If you can't just look at the code provided "Source Code" link at top, it can help you do something similar in your code.